# Wav big endian format in PDF

Tags: go, pdf, wav

When I parse PDF to extract .WAV from there it haven't headers. So I need to generate header for data in BigEndian format, because PDF WAV is stored in BigEndian and it is resource intensive to convert BigEndian to LittleEndian.
Here I have code which generates wav header with littleendian data and works good:

```
bits := 16
    pcmLen := len(samples) * 2
    samplingRate := format.sampleRate
    numChannels := format.channels
    blockAlign := (numChannels * bits) >> 3
    // jshint bitwise:true
    RIFF := 0x46464952 // Resource Interchange File Format
    WAVE := 0x45564157 // Wave
    FMT := 0x20746D66  // Format
    DATA := 0x61746164 // Audio Data
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(RIFF))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(32+pcmLen))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(WAVE))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(FMT))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(16))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint16(1))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint16(numChannels))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(samplingRate))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(samplingRate*blockAlign))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint16(blockAlign))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint16(bits))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(DATA))
    _ = binary.Write(buf, binary.LittleEndian, uint32(pcmLen))
```

How to generate header for bigEndian? Is it possible?
I have tried [RIFX](https://www.fileformat.info/format/riff/corion_rifx.htm) format but standard media players don't support it

Comment: What's the problem with replacing `LittleEndian` with `BigEndian` in this code?

Comment: @kostix this won't work. Player will not recognize the data

Comment: I think I've finally managed to get what you're after. So no, WAV (RIFF) files may only be big-endian when they start with the "RIFX" identifier, and if that does not work for you (and you have verified that with known-good files (not generated by your code)) then you have to find another solution. I have only managed to find [AIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) which is naturally BE and appears to contain PCM data as well as WAV. You might try to play with that format instead.

Comment: @kostix, thanks a lot